# PHP 5.4.4 throws filter_var() function not found error

Tags: php, apache

Following is the *only* php code I have inside the file `mailinglist.php`.

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST["name"]) && isset($_POST["email"]) ):
    $name = trim($_POST["name"]);
    $email = trim($_POST["email"]);
    if(filter_val($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        echo "Valid email";
    }
    else{
        echo "Invalid email provided.";
    }

if(filter_val($name, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING)) {
    echo "Valid name";
}
else {
    echo "Invalid name provided.";
}
?>
```

which logs the error (`/var/log/apache2/error.log`):

```
[Tue Jul 22 04:43:26 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function filter_val() in /var/www/mysite/mailinglist.php on line 22, referer: http://domain.com
```

Output of `php --version`:

```
PHP 5.4.4-14+deb7u12 (cli) (built: Jun 30 2014 13:15:11) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2012 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2012 Zend Technologies
```

Output of `php -m | grep filter`:

```
filter
```

Any idea why this happens? Let me know if you need any other info to help me with this.

Comment: typo. `filter_var` not `filter_val`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it must be `filter_var` instead of `filter_val`. That might be a typo.
[Check this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) for more

Comment: Haha you beat me by 3 seconds. +1

Answer (score 1):

There is no such function called `filter_val`.
What you are looking for is [`filter_var()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php)

Which you'd use like this:

```
if(filter_var($name, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING)) {
    echo "Valid name";
} else {
    echo "Invalid name provided.";
}
```